# show me an error when I generate apk in ionic

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Regards,
I have worked on a project, when I run it with ionic serve, it runs normally, but when I generate a test apk or try the tool to test it from my cell phone, the alert screens and data generated by an ngfor do not shows.
What could be the mistake

To test what I generated in ubuntu and windows 7

the console shows me these warnings:

Ionic Native: tried calling StatusBar.styleDefault, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html

Ionic Native: tried calling SplashScreen.hide, but Cordova is not available. Make sure to a) run in a real device or simulator and b) include cordova.js in your index.html

Comment: And did you include cordova.js in your index.html? are you using Angular7? Which android platform version?

Comment: Yes i include Córdova in HTML, the versión of angular is 7, platform Android API 27 oreo.